# Integrate System Voice Actions as It is in Twitter "Find [xyz] [on] [app_name]". "Search [xyz] on [app_name]" is already working

Tags: android, android-intent, actions-on-google, google-voice-actions

I want to integrate Google Voice Action to support user queries from `Google Assistant` like `Find xyz on app_name` or `Find xyz using app_name`.

I have successfully integrated `SEARCH_ACTION` which supports user query from `Google Assistant` like `Search xyz on app_name` or `Search xyz using app_name`. I have done this using [Search using a specific app](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#SearchOnApp).

How can I enable search with `Find` keyword? Twitter is supporting both options to Search using `Find` or `Search` keyword. But I am not able to find any documentation for this and it is not working with `SEARCH_ACTION` intent Filter.

Edit:

As per above documentation link, I have an Activity like,

```
<activity android:name=".SearchActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But this is only handling query like **`Search xyz on app_name`**.

Comment: Post what you've tried. As is, this question sounds like "do my work for me".

Comment: No, As I have mentioned in question. I have implemented "Search xyz on app_name" an It is working. I am not able to find any documentation for do the same using "Find" keyword. I am not asking Please do it for me. It's Just If you have any Idea about "Find" keyword in Google Assistant. If you have came across some documentation related to it Please share.

Comment: I have added the link to how I have done "Search xyz on app_name".

Comment: Your example code should be here, not in links to 3rd party sites.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing the Search intent (the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#SearchOnApp) you linked to) simply offers another app on the Android system the ability to call into your app by providing a generic search term. Exactly how other apps use this is up to them. One app may show an icon that links through, another may use a voice query like "search for X using app name".

Google Assistant in particular may or may not support those particular queries, but even if it does (or does not) today, that may change in the future depending on whatever the Google Assistant "app" does.

In other words, it's not really possible for you to choose exactly how this Search intent is called, only that when it is, your app responds to it appropriately.

Comment: I understand it works as per query supported by Google Assistant app. Twitter is working with query like "Find X on Twitter" so I was wondering if I am missing something / some documentation part which enables this. Even though Twitter is using "DialogFlow / Actions SDK" still I didn't find a way to directly launch my application from Fulfillment Response without any physical interaction of user.

Comment: If Twitter is working with this query then your app should as well I believe. If the query in Google Assistant is triggering their Android application then this isn't using DialogFlow or the Actions SDK. If it's not working, you could also try supporting Intent.ACTION_SEARCH (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEARCH) to see if that helps.